# Identify the children of an <li> tag on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<ul>
    <li><span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span class="parent overflow">Child<a><img src="../training/Test/Images/TDelete.png" class="iconTR" title="Delete Activity" width="13" id="1" height="13"></a></span>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <span class="parent overflow">grand Child<a><img src="../training/Test/Images/TDelete.png" class="iconTR" title="Delete Activity" id="2" width="13" height="13"></a></span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="parent overflow">Child<a><img src="../training/Test/Images/TDelete.png" class="iconTR" title="Delete Activity" id="3" width="13" height="13"></a></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </span></li>
</ul>
```

This is my code , on click of the image inside the span i want to find the id of all children(child,grand child ,great grand child etc) .It would be very helpful if you could answer my doubt . That is when i click on the image of the root node The id of all the child , grand child and great grand child should be retrieved in which the image belongs .I would like to work it strictly when i click on the image .

Comment: I dont see `id` attributes in any of the elements in your code

Comment: FYI you have an unclosed `<span>` tag

Comment: Do you maybe mean the id of all parents of the image? Your img tags have no children.

Comment: @Andrew I think the question was clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vrgu1a2h/)

```
$('img').on('click',function(){
   $(this).closest('li').find('img').each(function(){
      alert($(this).attr('id'));
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [find() method](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get all descendants of a certain element:

```
$("img").on("click",function() {
    var children = $(this).closest("li").find("*");
    console.log(children);
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tpuh3gu0/)